# type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String' flutter API

Tags: flutter, dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'package:selon_mart/model/product_fecth_all.dart';
import 'package:selon_mart/payment/payment_pulsa.dart';
import 'package:selon_mart/themes/fonts.dart';
import 'package:selon_mart/util/api.dart';

class ProductCoba extends StatefulWidget {
  Map<String, dynamic> data;

  ProductCoba({Key key, this.data});

  @override
  _ProductCobaState createState() => _ProductCobaState();
}

class _ProductCobaState extends State<ProductCoba> {
  List<ProductALL> _listProduk = [];

  var eurosInUSFormat = new NumberFormat.currency(
    locale: "eu",
    symbol: "",
    decimalDigits: 0,
  );

  getPref() async {
    SharedPreferences preferences = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    setState(() {
      getProductListBarang();
    });
  }

  int selected;

  // Future<Null> _getProductList() async {
  //   try {
  //     var response = await http.post(Env.product, body: {
  //       "customer": "C000150",
  //       "category": "DATA-TSEL",
  //     });
  //     final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
  //     _listProduk.clear();
  //     if (body['status'] == "ok") {
  //       print(response.body);
  //       for (var i = 0; i < body['data'].length; i++) {
  //         setState(() {
  //           ProductPulsa produk = ProductPulsa.fromJson(body['data'][i]);
  //           _listProduk.add(produk);
  //           print('get data reguler success');
  //         });
  //       }
  //     } else {
  //       print("Empty Result");
  //     }
  //   } catch (e) {
  //     print(e);
  //   }
  // }

  Future<Null> getProductListBarang() async {
    print("Login");
    try {
      // _showLoading("Please Wait...");
      SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();

      return http.get(await Env().productfecthall()).then((response) {
        print(response.body);

        final body = jsonDecode(response.body);
        _listProduk.clear();

        if (body["code"] == 200 && body["status"] == "OK") {
          print(response.body);
          for (var i = 0; i < body['product_list'].length; i++) {
            setState(() {
              ProductALL produk = ProductALL.fromJson(body['product_list'][i]);
              _listProduk.add(produk);
              print('get data product success');
            });
          }
        } else {
          print("Empty Result");
          // showDialog(
          //   barrierDismissible: false,
          //   context: context,
          //   builder: (BuildContext context) {
          //     return AlertDialog(
          //       title: Text(
          //         // body['data'],
          //         "Empty Result",
          //         style: ThemeFonts.textStyle500
          //             .copyWith(fontSize: 16, color: Colors.black),
          //       ),
          //       // content: Text("please Relogin"),
          //       // actions: <Widget>[
          //       //   new RaisedButton(
          //       //     child: Text('Ok'),
          //       //     textColor: Colors.grey,
          //       //     onPressed: () {
          //       //       // Navigator.pop(context);
          //       //       Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
          //       //         new MaterialPageRoute(
          //       //           builder: (_) {
          //       //             return LoginScreen();
          //       //           },
          //       //         ),
          //       //       );
          //       //     },
          //       //   ),
          //       // ],
          //     );
          //   },
          // );
        }
      }).catchError((error) {
        print(error);
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
    return null;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getPref();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.grey[300],
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
        children: <Widget>[
          Flexible(
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
              // width: 400,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
              child: ListView.builder(
                // gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                //   childAspectRatio: 7.7,
                //   crossAxisCount: 1,
                //   crossAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                // ),
                itemCount: _listProduk == null ? 0 : _listProduk.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return new Container(
                    child: new Center(
                      child: new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          GestureDetector(
                            onTap: () {
                              print(_listProduk[index].product_id);
                              _pilihMetodePembayaran();
                              setState(() {
                                selected = index;
                              });
                            },
                            child: new Card(
                              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(4.0),
                                side: index == selected
                                    ? BorderSide(color: Colors.red, width: 1.5)
                                    : BorderSide(
                                    color: Colors.transparent, width: 0),
                              ),
                              child: Column(
                                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                children: <Widget>[
                                  Row(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(
                                          10.0,
                                          10.0,
                                          0.0,
                                          10.0,
                                        ),
                                        child: new Text(
                                          "${_listProduk[index].productDesc}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SFCompactText',
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                      Padding(
                                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
                                        child: new Text(
                                          "Rp ${eurosInUSFormat.format(_listProduk[index].price)}",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                            fontFamily: 'SFCompactText',
                                            fontSize: 15.0,
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ),
                                  // Padding(
                                  //   padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                                  //   child: new Text(
                                  //     _listProduk[index].label,
                                  //     style: TextStyle(
                                  //       fontFamily: 'SFCompactText',
                                  //       fontSize: 15.0,
                                  //       color: Colors.black,
                                  //     ),
                                  //   ),
                                  // ),
                                ],
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }

  void _pilihMetodePembayaran() {
    Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(
      new MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (_) {
          return DetailPembayaranPulsa(
            data: {
              'produk': _listProduk[selected],
            },
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Model API

```
  String Id, product_id, name, category, productDesc, productType, productCategory, product_owner_id, product_owner_name,product_owner_profession, product_owner_category,
      product_owner_status, outlet_id, outlet_name,outlet_phone, outlet_email, outlet_address,outlet_province,
      outlet_city, outlet_district, outlet_subdistrict, outlet_zipcode, outlet_longitude, outlet_latitude,outlet_status,
      product_media_media_id, product_media_media_type, product_media_media_url, product_media_ceate_date, product_media_last_update, product_media_thumbnail_url,
      description, stock_type, stock_qty, promo, discount, rating, create_date, lst_update;

  int price;

  ProductALL({
    this.Id,
    this.product_id,
    this.name,
    this.category,
    this.product_owner_id,
    this.product_owner_name,
    this.product_owner_profession,
    this.product_owner_category,
    this.product_owner_status,
    this.outlet_id,
    this.outlet_name,
    this.outlet_phone,
    this.outlet_email,
    this.outlet_address,
    this.outlet_province,
    this.outlet_city,
    this.outlet_district,
    this.outlet_subdistrict,
    this.outlet_zipcode,
    this.outlet_longitude,
    this.outlet_latitude,
    this.outlet_status,
    this.product_media_media_id,
    this.product_media_media_type,
  this.product_media_media_url,
  this.product_media_ceate_date,
  this.product_media_last_update,
  this.product_media_thumbnail_url,
    this.description,
  this.price,
  this.stock_type,
  this.stock_qty,
  this.promo,
  this.discount,
  this.rating,
  this.create_date,
    this.lst_update,
  });

  factory ProductALL.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> parsedJson) {
    return ProductALL(
        Id: parsedJson['Id'],
        product_id: parsedJson['product_id'],
        name: parsedJson['name'],
        category: parsedJson['category'],
        product_owner_id: parsedJson['product_owner']['id'],
        product_owner_name: parsedJson['product_owner']['name'],
        product_owner_profession: parsedJson['product_owner']['profession'],
        product_owner_category: parsedJson['product_owner']['category'],
        product_owner_status: parsedJson['product_owner']['status'],
        outlet_id: parsedJson['outlet']['id'],
        outlet_name: parsedJson['outlet']['name'],
        outlet_phone: parsedJson['outlet']['phone'],
        outlet_email: parsedJson['outlet']['email'],
        outlet_address: parsedJson['outlet']['address'],
        outlet_province: parsedJson['outlet']['province'],
        outlet_city: parsedJson['outlet']['city'],
        outlet_district: parsedJson['outlet']['district'],
        outlet_subdistrict: parsedJson['outlet']['subdistrict'],
        outlet_zipcode: parsedJson['outlet']['zipcode'],
        outlet_longitude: parsedJson['outlet']['longitude'],
        outlet_latitude: parsedJson['outlet']['latitude'],
        outlet_status: parsedJson['outlet']['status'],
        product_media_media_id: parsedJson['product_media']['media_id'],
        product_media_media_type: parsedJson['product_media']['media_type'],
        product_media_media_url: parsedJson['product_media']['media_url'],
        product_media_thumbnail_url: parsedJson['product_media']['thumbnail_url'],
        product_media_ceate_date: parsedJson['product_media']['ceate_date'],
        product_media_last_update: parsedJson['product_media']['last_update'],
      description: parsedJson['description'],
      price: parsedJson['price'],
      stock_type: parsedJson['stock_type'],
      stock_qty: parsedJson['stock_qty'],
      promo: parsedJson['promo'],
      discount: parsedJson['discount'],
      rating: parsedJson['rating'],
      create_date: parsedJson['create_date'],
      lst_update: parsedJson['lst_update'],
    );
  }
}
```

ERROR Code :

I/flutter ( 7688): {"status":"OK","code":200,"product_list":[{"Id":"UlxiRHgBpkgmiq4s4Rcn","product_id":195520,"name":"Tas Jinjing Wanita Keren","category":"fashion","product_owner":[{"id":173232,"name":"Naifz","profession":"Musician, Alternative Pop Band","category
":"fashion","status":1},{"id":173235,"name":"D-Masiv","profession":"Band, Pop","category":"fashion","status":1}],"outlet":[{"id":171986,"name":"outlet blok-m","phone":"081212392949","email":"blokm@selonmarket.com","address":"jln. blok-m, No. 1s","province":"DKI Jak
arta","city":"Jakarta Selatan","district":"Blok M","subdistrict":"Gandaria","zipcode":"13415","longitude":-6.2456781,"latitude":106.7998651,"status":1}],"product_media":[{"media_id":195520,"media_type":"image/jpeg","media_url":"http://admin-selonmarket.kiselindones
ia.net/api/v1/admin/find/item/original/image/f3ec8f73f1b55a66bab19d455801487c2b8c2d1ac993ce78eecdf16933504a71","thumbnail_url":"http://admin-selonmarket.kiselindonesia.net/api/v1/admin/find/item/thumbnail/image/f3ec8f73f1b55a66bab19d455801487c2b8c
I/flutter ( 7688): {"status":"OK","code":200,"product_list":[{"Id":"UlxiRHgBpkgmiq4s4Rcn","product_id":195520,"name":"Tas Jinjing Wanita Keren","category":"fashion","product_owner":[{"id":173232,"name":"Naifz","profession":"Musician, Alternative Pop Band","category
":"fashion","status":1},{"id":173235,"name":"D-Masiv","profession":"Band, Pop","category":"fashion","status":1}],"outlet":[{"id":171986,"name":"outlet blok-m","phone":"081212392949","email":"blokm@selonmarket.com","address":"jln. blok-m, No. 1s","province":"DKI Jak
arta","city":"Jakarta Selatan","district":"Blok M","subdistrict":"Gandaria","zipcode":"13415","longitude":-6.2456781,"latitude":106.7998651,"status":1}],"product_media":[{"media_id":195520,"media_type":"image/jpeg","media_url":"http://admin-selonmarket.kiselindones
ia.net/api/v1/admin/find/item/original/image/f3ec8f73f1b55a66bab19d455801487c2b8c2d1ac993ce78eecdf16933504a71","thumbnail_url":"http://admin-selonmarket.kiselindonesia.net/api/v1/admin/find/item/thumbnail/image/f3ec8f73f1b55a66bab19d455801487c2b8c
I/flutter ( 7688): type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'String'

Comment: This code shouldn't work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Type int is not a subtype of string means you r placing integer value in string data type either parse that value in string or convert the data type to string.